# How to get the time in 24 without formatting to a string

Tags: c#, datetime

I'm trying to compare the current hour to see if it's past 16 h (4 o clock in the afternoon)

```
int temps = new TimeSpan(16, 0, 0).Hours;
 int now = DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay.Hours;
 int result=1;

            if (now > temps)
                result = 2;
```

but if I want `now` to be displayed like this 14h or 15h without having to do this

```
now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm")
```

because I need to compare it to `temps` so I need it as an integer

is it possible? All my research led to advising me to use the to string format

I have tried : `int now = DateTime.NowUTC.TimeOfDay.Hours;` which displayed 17h but the problem is that it's the time in the UK and I live in Canada

Comment: Do you mean if it's 4pm, `DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay.Hours` is really `4` instead of `16`? I can't believe this.

Comment: Use `DateTime.Now` instead of `DateTime.UTCNow` if you want local instead of UTC time?  `TimeOfDay.Hours` is exactly how you get the hours from the time of day.  Or even just `DateTime.Now.Hour`.  It's not really clear to me exactly what the problem is here.

Comment: Just because it displays the time as am/pm does not mean that it stored differently. And `DateTime.Now.Hour` is the same as `DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay.Hours`. And `int temps = new TimeSpan(16, 0, 0).Hours;` is exactly the same as `int temps = 16;`

Comment: But I don't want to get  4 PM and I want to get  16

Comment: @napi15: When the time is 4:00PM, `DateTime.Now.Hours` returns `16`.  As does `DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay.Hours`.  Please clarify the actual problem you're encountering.  Perhaps your computer clock is off by 12 hours and you haven't noticed?  Perhaps your testing is based on a faulty assumption and the results are incorrect?  Something else?  You'll need to describe and demonstrate the actual problem in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `DateTime` is always stored the same way internally, no matter how it is displayed. Whenever you see a date, it means that is has been converted to a string and formatted. Even in the debugger! What you see is just a temporary representation of the **real** `DateTime` stored as a number.

The documentation of the [DateTime.Hour Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.hour%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) says:

> The value of the Hour property is always expressed using a 24-hour clock.

This real `DateTime` is internally stored as the time which elapsed since a reference date. The documentation of the [DateTime Structure](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime(v=vs.110).aspx) says:

> Time values are measured in 100-nanosecond units called ticks, and a particular date is the number of ticks since 12:00 midnight, January 1, 0001 A.D. (C.E.) in the GregorianCalendar calendar (excluding ticks that would be added by leap seconds). For example, a ticks value of 31241376000000000L represents the date, Friday, January 01, 0100 12:00:00 midnight.

---

You can write

```
int now = DateTime.Now.Hour; // Always expressed using a 24-hour clock.
int result = 1;

if (now > 16)
    result = 2;
```

Or more concise

```
int result = DateTime.Now.Hour > 16 ? 2 : 1;
```

Don't use `NowUTC` if you want your local time. This yields what was once called [Greenwich Mean Time (GMT)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greenwich_Mean_Time).

Comment: Thank you , now I understand better . Writing `int result = DateTime.Now.Hour > 16 ? 2 : 1;` did achieved what I want . I just didn't know till you well explained it , thank again